# How to configure a simple Trex Traffic Generator test using Mininet?

Tags: mininet, dpdk, network-traffic, network-tools

I want to simply send packets from one host to another but I'm confused about how to configure the configuration file and/or src_ip and dst_ip in my Python Script.

Hosts info route:

```
Host  Destination   Gateway      Genmask
h1    10.0.1.0      10.0.1.10    255.255.255.0
h2    10.0.2.0      10.0.2.20    255.255.255.0
```

My current ip's configuration file:

```
- ip: 10.0.1.1           # Port_0 in h1
  default_gw: 10.0.2.1   # Port_0 in h2
- ip: 10.0.1.2           # Port_1 in h1
  default_gw: 10.0.2.2   # Port_1 in h2
```

I run the server in h1 with: *./t-rex-64 -i --stl*
And open another terminal and run a simple ping code:

```
from trex_stl_lib.api import *

c = STLClient(server = '10.0.1.1')
c.connect()

try:
    c.reset(ports = 0)
    c.set_service_mode(ports = port_0)

    c.set_verbose('normal')
    c.ping_ip(src_port = 0, dst_ip = '10.0.2.2', pkt_size = 64, count = 5)

except STLError as e:
    print(e)

finally:
    c.set_verbose('low')
    c.set_service_mode(ports = port_0, enabled = False)
    c.disconnect()
```

I can connect to the server, but my pings never arrive.
I believe I'm doing something wrong with my IP's. I've seen some places use 16.0.0.0 and 48.0.0.0 but couldn't find anything else. Any helps is appreciated!